# Check the SMS Order in Android

Tags: android, smsmanager

I'm sending 5 messages via android `SmsManager` and need to check the delivery order. Are the SMSs that are sent in an order delivered in the same order or not. If not, what is the order of delivery?

I think I can do it by `BroadcastReceiver` to check the delivery but how about the order?

Thanks

Comment: "Are the SMSs that are sent in an order delivered in the same order or not" -- I would not count on that, if you are sending the second before you know that the first has been received. "If not, what is the order of delivery?" -- whatever order the mobile carrier wants.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you, I just want to find out the order. Don't want to control the order.

Comment: Can' t I attach something like an ID to the SMS that I can check it in deliver `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: @MustafaMohammadi, to get notified when the message is delivered you'll provide a PendingIntent to the send method of SmsManager. When you get the callback from the system you can internally check the order of delivery. I don't have a device in front of me to check, but if you inspect the Intent you get back it'll contain information that'll let you map it to the sent SMS.